# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, ascii, decoding

I have a lxml.objectify.StringElement which is named elm and is:

```
u'\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266bHow do you get a job on the Yahoo staff when you are older?\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b?'
```

I want to turn it to a str:

```
str(elm)
```

But I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Python 2 or 3?  Unicode and strings are handled very differently between the two versions.

Comment: And what do you expect the string output to be? Note that you *already* have Unicode text there. Why do you need a byte string? What encodings can you use for the bytes?

Comment: I suggest you read this: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: this is the part of my code:                                   string_of_words = str(elm)
list_of_words = string_of_words.split(' ')
array_of_words = np.array(list_of_words)     I needed to do some operation to each word in the elm so I thought this way I could extract each word, any other better way?

Comment: How much do you understand about Unicode vs. encoded text already? Perhaps you should first make sure you understand what the difference is. See the [Python Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html), the Joel on Software article aquavitae pointed you to, as well as [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html).

Comment: `unicode(elm).encode('utf-8')` should work... But if you deal with unicode, you should really directly work with it instead of needing to convert it to a `str`.

Comment: using `utf-8` I got this `ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½How do you get a job on the Yahoo staff when you are older?ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½ΓÖ½?` I guess this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: it gave me:      '\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xabHow do you get a job on the Yahoo staff when you are older?\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab\xe2\x99\xab?'
but I need to know what are in elm :(

Comment: That's the utf-8 encoded `str` version of your `elem`. What else do you need?

Comment: I am reading a senescence from a file and trying to see what words we have in it, and filter some of the. but my program crashes at this point.

Comment: this is the sentence that I am reading from xml file:    <subject>â™«â™«â™«â™«â™«â™«â™«How do you get a job on the Yahoo staff when you are older?â™«â™«â™«â™«â™«?</subject>

Comment: is there any way that I can make the program ignore the error and continue to the other sentences?

Comment: That's a very basic Python question. The answer is `try`/`except`. But there obviously is no workaround for the fact that basic byte strings can only accommodate a subset of the full Unicode repertoire. How do you plan to cope if your input contains *voilá* or *Ångström*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into a similar situation and something like this worked for me (I can't find the code now):

```
a=u'\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266bHow do you get a job on the Yahoo staff when you are older?\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b\u266b?'
print bytes(a.encode('utf-32'))
```

But I get this with your string:

```
��k&k&k&k&k&k&k&How do you get a job on the Yahoo staff when you are older?k&k&k&k&k&?
```

Hah! I know this may not help you, but maybe it will be a step in the right direction. By the way, you might want to try Python 3+, it's much better at unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any conversions, file content is unicode by default. Just remove `str`. All the string methods are applicable on unicode, so splitting will be OK.
If you want unicode out of some object, try use of `unicode` instead of `str`

Comment: thanks for your reply. but the elm is a lxml.objectify.StringElement and it does not support splitting :(

Comment: @someone, have you tred using `unicode` instead of `str`? Also there probably is some unicode value text field inside this object. Have you inspected that?